# How do I use PHP to construct an SQL query to sort and select from multiple rows in my database

Tags: php, sql, unity-game-engine

I'm building a game using a platform called Unity. The game integrates with some php scripts and a database I have. Players can register in the game and all info gets stored in the database, including their high score.

I'm trying to write php code that will query the database and complete the following action

***Sort the table by high score**

***Return the "username" and "high score" values for the top 25 entries**

I don't know how to construct a query to do this. Below is a screen cap of my table and a sample php script of a query used to log in

[database of users and high scores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBJH7.png)

//php below, script checking that there is only one instance of the username

```
$namecheckquery = "SELECT username, totalpoints, highscore FROM players WHERE username='" . $username . "'"; 

$namecheck = mysqli_query($con, $namecheckquery) or die("2: Name check query failed"); //error code #2 - name check query failed
if (mysqli_num_rows($namecheck) != 1)
{
    echo "5: Either no user with name or more than one"; //error code #5: number of names matching does not = 1 
    exit();
}

$existinginfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($namecheck);
```

Comment: Sorry, [we can't accept images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: fixed. See above for edited post

Answer (score 0):

You need `ORDER BY {column_name} {ASC|DESC}` (ascending by default), and then `LIMIT BY {offset}, {length}`:

```
SELECT username, hightscore
FROM players
ORDER BY highscore DESC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

You can also add multiple columns to order by, so in case of equality the next column will be used, like:

```
SELECT username, hightscore
FROM players
ORDER BY highscore DESC, totalpoints DESC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this stored as anything? This request goes through a php script, and I want to return the results through php back to the game

Comment: Yes, use the same logic as your name check example without the `mysqli_num_rows` part

Comment: It looks like you have a number of questions regarding a number of different areas of interest, like needing help with Unity, a means of network communication, server scripting, as well as your database. If you structure your question for yourself into these groups, you will guaranteed find that those questions have been answered already here on Stack Overflow.